# How to work with combineReducer in ReactRedux? And combineReducers's 'sate' object to the multiple reduces

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have recently started working on react web development application, and started using react redux saga for my application. So the issue is I have created two reduces **reducer1** , **reducer2** and used **combineReducers** but the state is not sending back to *propsToState* on my **Component**.

**Note:** If i'm using single reducer it is working fine

Example code:

**My store**

```
// create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const rootReducers = combineReducers({reduce1, reducer2})

// create a redux store with our reducer above and middleware
let store = createStore(
  rootReducers,
  compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);



// run the saga

function* rootSaga () {
  yield all([
      fork(saga1),
      fork(saga2),
  ]);
}

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

**My reducers**

```
// reducer with initial state
const initialState = {
    p1: false,
    p2: null,
    p3: null
  };

  export function reducer1(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log(state);
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTION1:
        return { ...state, p1: true, p3: null };
      case ACTION2:
        const lState = { ...state, p1: false, p2: action.data };
        return lState;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

*note:* and reduce2 is similar to the reducer1

**On my component**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loggining: state.loggining,
    user: state.user,
    error: state.error
  };
};
```

Comment: In your code I just see one reducer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing key  which should be reducers name while fetching the state mapped to particular reducer.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loggining: state.reducer1 .loggining, //add key reducer1
    user: state.reducer1 .user,
    error: state.reducer1.error
  };
};
```

Please find more [`details here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677755/react-native-redux-map-state-to-props-not-working/47678484#47678484)

Comment: thanks buddy, this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677755/react-native-redux-map-state-to-props-not-working/47678484#47678484