# Simple Redux app, only with Counter returns undefined when I use combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have simple counter app with two counters. Everythings works fine untill I try to use `combineReducers()`.

Here is my **reducer file**:

```
const reducerCounter = (state={counterBarca:0,counterReal:0}, action) => {
  console.log(action.type);
  console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_BARCA':
      return { ...state, counterBarca: state.counterBarca + 1};
    case 'INCREMENT_REAL':
      return { ...state, counterReal: state.counterReal + 1 };
    default:
      return state;
    }
};

export default reducerCounter;
```

Here is a part of my **Counter file** where I have buttons.

```
.
.
.

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps', state.counterBarca);
  return {
    counterBarca: state.counterBarca,
    counterReal: state.counterReal,
   };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIncrementBarca: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_BARCA' }),
    onIncrementReal: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_REAL' })
  }
};

Counter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

export default Counter;
```

And finally my **App.js** where I have imported my reducer and component which displays buttons and counters:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers/reducerCounter';


//components
import Counter from './components/Counter';

import './App.css';

const store = createStore(reducer);
.
.
.
```

When I am trying to use **combineReducers** and import it inside my **App.js** the counters not works. It shows me `undefined` when I `console.log` my counters. Why is that ? Why when I use combinereducers the counter shows me nothing (it is `undefined` then)?

Comment: You didn't show a piece of code where you're using `combineReducers`, please update your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native redux map state to props not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677755/react-native-redux-map-state-to-props-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mapStateToProps` wrong. Use it like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps', state.counterBarca);
  return {
    counterBarca: state.reducerCounter.counterBarca,
    counterReal: state.reducerCounter.counterReal,
   };
};
```

Notice this part please:

```
    counterBarca: state.reducerCounter.counterBarca,
    counterReal: state.reducerCounter.counterReal,
```

Here I used `reducerCounter` for your reducer state in your global state. Use it how do you open in your `combineReducers` function. So, you are trying to get a `counterBarca` in your global `state` but actually it is in somewhere else like `state.reducerCounter.counterBarca`.

Comment: Simple as that ! Works great :).

Comment: Yes, simple but a common mistake :) If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. So in the list it is shown as a question which has an accepted answer.